# Unix cat to output only range of rows

Tags: shell, unix, cat

How can I get output of `cat` command to show me only output from 85 to 158 line of the file.
I know I can add the numbers to each lime and then maybe pipe it, but I don't want to delete numbers latter.

Or should I maybe use some other text parser?
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use sed:

```
sed -n '85,158p' file
```

or

```
head -n 158 file | tail -n 73 # 158-85=73
```

Comment: Thx, works like a charm :D I'll accept it in 5 min. head + tail nice one :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this also:

```
cat file | sed -n '85,158p' file
```

Answer (score 1):

> sed '85,158!d' file

This command work correctly for your expecting.

Comment: An explanation of how and why this works could also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use awk. Here is a sample script, print_line_range.sh:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# change the above line to where env located in your system, e.g. #!/bin/env bash

start_line_number=$1
end_line_number=$2
filepath=$3

cmd="awk 'NR >= ${start_line_number} && NR <= ${end_line_number} {print NR, \$0}' ${filepath}"
#use {print \$0}' if don't want print line number
eval "$cmd"
```

Sample usage,

```
print_line_range.sh <start_line_number> <end_line_number> <filepath>
```